# Speed up "for" loop on sparse matrix

Tags: python, performance, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse (n_item, n_item) co-occurence matrix (cell (i,j) represents number of times that i and j were seen together).

From there, I want to produce a (n_item, n_item) similarity matrix where cell (i,j) would have the jaccard distance between *item i* and *item j*.

Here's my current code :

```py
### coordinates and scores are csr matrices
for i,j,v in zip(coordinates.row, coordinates.col, coordinates.data):
    if v != 0:
        occAandB = v
        occAnoB = row_sum[i] - occAandB
        occBnoA = column_sum[j] - occAandB
        scores[i,j] = occAandB/(occAndB+occAnoB+occBnoA)
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to get to the final *scores* matrix indicated above.

Looking forward to your answers !

Comment: Provide a complete working example, with a real, but small, sparse matrix.  If you look at good accepted answers to other questions, you'll see they always include real calculations, ones that show the equivalence between the OP's case and the improved code.  Save us some work.

Comment: Also, you don't define row sum etc.